# Error in uploading the image to server

Tags: android, base64, image-uploading

Now i am doing to upload the sdcard selected image to the server. I am very new to this concept.  My code is here. http://pastie.org/9867601#7,88,161 . I can change my byte array into base 64 string. The length is too long. When the length is small only it will upload. The string based on the selected image. If the image size is big means the string also too long. If i tried to upload my big size images i got the error like that.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-  
 //W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">      
<html>  
 <head>        
 <title>503 Service Unavailable</title>   
 <style type="text/css">           
 #page {width: 416px; padding: 10px; margin: 200px auto; border: 1px solid  grey; background-color: #DFDFDF;}        
 body {background-color: #CCC; margin: auto;                  font-family: Helvetica, Ariel, sans-serif;}         
 </style>      
 </head>        
 <body>        
    <div id="page">            
    <h1>Page Could Not Be Loaded</h1>      
    <p>We're very sorry, but the page could not be loaded properly. This should be fixed very soon, and we apologize for any inconvenience.</p> 
    </div>        </body>      </html>
```

Now my questions are:

1. What is the error says?
2. Am i convert my bye array to Base 64 String?
3. If its correct means why it shouldn't work?
4. Is it any possible to create small Base 64 string?
5. Do we have any other options to upload the image to server other than this?

I am really struggling a lot. Can anybody help me to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *What is the error says?* error said: "Page Could Not Be Loaded..." *Am i convert my bye array to Base 64 String?* You should know this, it is your code. *If its correct means why it shouldn't work?* maybe server doesn't like you *Is it any possible to create small Base 64 string?* yes, is "IA=="  small enough? *Do we have any other options to upload the image to server other than this?* A lots of

Answer (score 1):

1. i think that error from server side
2. -
3. -
4. you can resize the picture before convert it to base64 but it will decrease your image quality
5. use multipart

   example: https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/